# ternary operation in js

Tags: javascript, ternary

Maybe I do not understand ternary operation but

if I am right it's

```
    test ? true : false
```

So this should give

```
function toto(x, y)
{ 
    return (x > 0 ? x < 7 ? true : false : false &&
                y > 0 ? y < 6 ? true : false : false)
}
```

true only if 0

but if I do

```
toto(4,6)
```

it returns true, why? What am I missing ?

Comment: what is your input for `toto` for which you expect true or false?

Comment: never tried this one... probably you have to add () around the second condition... anyway it's pretty unreadable code and i would not reccomend to do it this way...

Comment: Why do you expect `false` for `4, 6`?

Comment: Why did you make your *ternary* operator into *quaternary*?

Comment: In real life you should never use `x ? true : false` – it's just redundant, and if you really need to make sure the value is a boolean make it either `!!x` or `Boolean(x)`. Also, you should never use nested ternary operations either because they're just about impossible to read.

Comment: The reason you're having trouble understanding what it's doing is because it's difficult to read. Why not write the expression as `(x > 0 && x < 7) && (y > 0 && y < 6)`

Comment: you can also rewrite it to `x > 0 ? x < 7 ? y > 0 ? y < 6 ? true : false : false  : false : false`

Comment: @appleapple ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do like this :

```
function toto(x, y)
{ 
    return (x > 0 ? x < 7 ? true : false : false ) &&
                ( y > 0 ? y < 6 ? true : false : false)
}
```

with the bracket before and after the exp1 and exp2 
and yes it's a bit unreadable ^^

**edit :** I also would do

```
return (x > 0 && x < 7) && (y > 0 && y < 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `eslint` to format your code ,this is the formatted code,see:

```
function toto(x, y) {
  return x > 0
    ? x < 7
      ? true
      : false
    : false && y > 0
      ? y < 6
        ? true
        : false
      : false
}
```

image:

[image]
I think ,it is easier to understand

Comment: I don't quite understand what those red arrows are supposed to mean.

Comment: @JJJ,the execution order of `todo(4,6)`

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to achieve this? chceking whether the `x` is from 0..7 and `y` is 0..6?

```
function toto(x, y)
{ 
return (x > 0 && x < 7) && (y > 0 && y < 6 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence affecting it here

```
function toto(x, y)
{ 
return ((x > 0 ? x < 7 ? true : false : false) && (y > 0 ? y < 6 ? true : false : false)) 
}
```